# How do I connect Entourage clients to a SharePoint calendar?

Tags: sharepoint, mac-osx, calendar, mac

I have a SharePoint site on my intranet that includes a calendar list.  We have the following instructions for Windows clients:

1. go to the calendar page (http://sharepoint.intranet/sites/my_site/Lists/Calendar/MyItems.aspx)
2. click "Actions ▼"
3. click "Connect to Outlook"
4. follow the instructions within Outlook

But on OSX, there is no "Connect to Outlook." There is "Connect to Client," but users get a message about not knowing the "stssync" protocol.  I've tried adding calendars from within Entourage, but I can only figure out how to add another user's calendar, not a SharePoint one.

Any help?

Comment: Of pure curiosity: How did you get the calendar? Is it an add-on? Does it get data from exchange? (I want to learn Sharepoint) :)

Comment: It's just a list that has a "calendar-ey" feel. I don't believe it's an add-on, but it may not be a terribly well-known feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this.  Entourage is a very limited mail client and isn't a Mac version of Outlook exactly.  In fact, Entourage accesses mail via Outlook Web Access, so in a way you can consider it more on par with the features of OWA than with the Outlook client.

Perhaps just making the link to the SharePoint calendar more accessible is your best answer.  I don't know if they'll be more options in Snow Leopard, but I hear the Mail app will natively support Exchange, and thus will likely become a better option than Entourage.  We'll have to wait and see if that means SharePoint calendar support as well.

Comment: I believe they announced that they would support calendar syncing as well using the native Calendar app that is on OS X. Of course this does require an upgrade. But it's only $29 for a single machine and I do know there is a family pack (Isn't a company a big happy family?).